# Gentoo - iwlwifi: Unknown symbol dev_coredumsg (err -2)

Tags: wifi, drivers, gentoo

Recently I installed Gentoo on my Lenovo legion 5 laptop

After following the iwlwifi guide, wireless interface still doesn't appear in the ip link list

Here is output of dmesg | grep iwlwifi

`[   5.157163] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol dev_coredumpsg (err -2)`

My wifi card is Intel AX 200

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. The problem in my case was that I had mistakenly compiled cfg80211 as a built-in, instead of as a module as the [Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Iwlwifi#Kernel) suggests:

```
[*] Networking support  --->
    [*] Wireless  --->
        <M>   cfg80211 - wireless configuration API
        [ ]     nl80211 testmode command
        [ ]     enable developer warnings
        [ ]     cfg80211 certification onus
        [*]     enable powersave by default
        [ ]     cfg80211 DebugFS entries
        [ ]     support CRDA
        [ ]     cfg80211 wireless extensions compatibility
        <M>   Generic IEEE 802.11 Networking Stack (mac80211)
        [ ]   Minstrel
              *** Some wireless drivers require a rate control algorithm ***
        [ ]   Enable mac80211 mesh networking (pre-802.11s) support
        -*-   Enable LED triggers
        [ ]   Export mac80211 internals in DebugFS
        [ ]   Trace all mac80211 debug messages
        [ ]   Select mac80211 debugging features  ----
```

You should review your kernel config and make sure you have set the appropriate values.